# Partial views inside my asp.net mvc will ignore all the model data annotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have the following action method which render the following partial view:-

```
        public ActionResult CreateVMNetwork(int vmid)
        {
            AssignIps vmips = new AssignIps()
            {
                TechnologyIP = new TechnologyIP() { TechnologyID = vmid},
                IsTMSIPUnique = true,
                IsTMSMACUnique = true
            };
            return PartialView("_CreateNetworkInfo",vmips);
        }
```

The partial view is :-

```
model TMS.ViewModels.AssignIps

    @if (this.ViewContext.FormContext == null) 
{
    this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); 
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateVMNetwork", "VirtualMachine", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "networktable",
    LoadingElementId = "loadingimag",
    HttpMethod= "POST",
    OnSuccess="submitform"





}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.TechnologyIP.TechnologyID)

 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
<span class="f">IP Address</span> 

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.IPAddress)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.IPAddress)                                              

   <input type="CheckBox" name="IsTMSIPUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsTMSMACUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> IP Unique.    | 
 <span class="f"> MAC Address</span>       
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.MACAddress)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.MACAddress)                                              

 <input type="CheckBox" name="IsTMSMACUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsTMSMACUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> MAC Unique.

</div>


       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

but all the data annotation on the view model will not fire on the partial view , the AssignIps view model class is :-

```
namespace TMS.ViewModels
{
    public class AssignIps
    {
        public TechnologyIP TechnologyIP { get; set; }

        public bool IsTMSIPUnique  { get; set; }
        public bool IsTMSMACUnique { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and he TechnologyIP model class is :-

```
namespace TMS.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TechnologyIP_Validation))]

    public partial class TechnologyIP
    {}}


namespace TMS.Models
{
    public class TechnologyIP_Validation
    {
        [Required]
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
```

but the [Required] data annotation on the TechnologyIP model, will not fire on the partial view,, can anyone adovce please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sections defined in your layout view don't get populated when using `PartialViewResult`, so the unobtrusive validation scripts are not being added.

You can test this by creating an action on your controller that just returns a partial view, and then call this via `$.get()` (using jQuery, obviously). If you use `console.log()`, you can inspect the result in Firebug. You could also use something like Fiddler; regardless, if you look at the HTML returned you will not see the script references anywhere.

Comment: but the unobrrusice validation scripts were populated from the main view, which call the partial views ? is not this enough ?

Comment: If the partial is loaded after the page (via Ajax), then no. The unobtrusive scripts only run once, on DOM ready.

Comment: but i am referencing this @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}, inside my partial view. so the unobtrusive scripts should work on the partial views DOM.? am i right ?

Comment: No. `@section` assignments are ignored in partial views. You can try rendering the scripts directly into the view (call `@Scripts.Render` without specifying a section with `@section`).

Comment: you are 100% right . i wrote  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
at the end of my partial view and it worked well.thanks

Comment: but now as i am referencing the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") twice; one at the main view and the other at the partial view. so now if i click on any ajax.begin form submit button , the application will send two ajax calls to the server. do u know why i am facing this issue. i think it is related to the fact that i am referencing the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") twice ,, what do u think about this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, a wrong practice is to have:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}

in the partial view, try to do it just putting

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

and it should work!